# How do I add listener to new page entering in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop an extension to Google Chrome and I'm looking for a listener that can notify my extension when getting to a new page (that means according to my definition that the address was changed) and allow me to process the address of the page and react accordingly (like changing the badge).

Can anyone please refer me to such listener ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event which fires if the tab's url has changed.